# Compile 64 bit Mexfile for Matlab with OpenCV function

Tags: matlab, 64-bit, opencv, mex

Hey people!
I use a function of the opencv library with Matlab (2008), where I got a mexw32 file from. Unfortunately these don't work on a 64 Bit Windows 7 system anymore, where Matlab automatically installs as 64 bit version. 
What do I need to compile the 64 bit version? I don't have the original C files, but the function is just a wrapper for an opencv function.
(I can have VisualStudio 2008 or 2010 for compilation)

Thank you for any advice or tip!

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB 64bit is really going to want a 64bit MEX file. You can down the latest opencv version [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) but without the wrapper code you're in trouble for a quick fix. However, if you're familiar with MEX then you may be able to just rewrite a simple wrapper for the functionality that you need.

Alternately, if you purchased and registered your product with Mathworks you may be able to log into your account at [matlab.com](http://matlab.com) and download a 32bit version of the entire MATLAB application depending on how it is licensed. Keep in mind Mathworks will let you do a fresh download even if your service contract is expired---you'll just only be able to get what you purchased previously.